# has_many :through add extra param in join table in one call (object creation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have the following code letting a user to create a new album through a join table with an extra params (creator).

In order to do it, my controller does 2 requests (one for creating the album object and the collaboration object / the other to update the collaboration object with the extra params).

I would like to know if there is a way to do this call with only one request. (add the extra "creator" params in the same time than the album creation)

Thank you.

#### albums_controller.rb

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @album = current_user.albums.build
  end

  def create
    @album = current_user.albums.build(album_params)
    if current_user.save
      @album.collaborations.first.update_attribute :creator, true
      redirect_to user_albums_path(current_user), notice: "Saved."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

    def album_params
      params.require(:album).permit(:name)
    end

end
```

#### Album.rb

```
class Album < ApplicationRecord

  # Relations
  has_many :collaborations
  has_many :users, through: :collaborations

end
```

#### Collaboration.rb

```
class Collaboration < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :user
end
```

#### User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :collaborations
  has_many :albums, through: :collaborations
end
```

#### views/albums/new

```
= simple_form_for [:user, @album] do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.button :submit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add associated objects on the new album instance:

```
@album = current_user.albums.new(album_params)
@album.collaborations.new(user: current_user, creator: true)
```

When you call `@album.save` ActiveRecord will automatically save the associated records in the same transaction.

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @album = current_user.albums.new
  end

  def create
    @album = current_user.albums.new(album_params)
    @album.collaborations.new(user: current_user, creator: true)
    if @album.save
      redirect_to user_albums_path(current_user), notice: "Saved."
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

    def album_params
      params.require(:album).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

You are also calling `current_user.save` and not `@album.save`. The former does work due to fact that it causes AR to save the associations but is not optimal since it triggers an unessicary update of the user model.

Comment: `.build` is just an alias for `.new` thats hanging around for compatibility.